# How to make input affect an echo

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

In this problem, when I sum a number to the quantity with the button,I want to change the total but it doesnt change, which is this line:

```
<td width="20%" class="Text-center"><?php echo number_format($producto['PRECIO']*$producto['CANTIDAD'],2);  ?></td>
```

Here's the php code

```
  <tr>
        <td width="40%"><?php echo $producto['NOMBRE'] ?></td>
        <td><button onclick="add_number()">mas</button><input type="text" id="suma" name="suma" value="<?php echo $producto['CANTIDAD'] ?>" readonly="readonly"></input></td>
        <td width="20%" class="Text-center"><?php echo $producto['PRECIO'] ?></td>
        <td width="20%" class="Text-center"><?php echo number_format($producto['PRECIO']*$producto['CANTIDAD'],2);  ?></td>
        <td width="5%">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" 
                name="id" 
                value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['ID'],COD,KEY); ?>">



                <button 
                class="btn btn-danger" 
                type="submit"
                name="btnAccion"
                value="Eliminar"
                >Eliminar</button>

            </form>

    </td>
    </tr>
```

Here's the Java code:

```
function add_number() {

    var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("suma").value);
    var result = first_number + 1;

    document.getElementById("suma").value = result

}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `add_number` where you increment the quantity value, you can also add the price to total cell of table each time, change your JavaScript function like this:

```
function add_number() {
    var suma = parseInt(document.getElementById("suma").value); /* get current quantity */
    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML); /* get current total */
    var percio = parseInt(document.getElementById("percio").innerHTML); /* get price */

    document.getElementById("suma").value = suma + 1; /* change quantity */
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = (suma + percio).toFixed(2); /* change total */

}
```

Note the usage of `innerHTML` and `value`. The difference is because `value` is used for `<input>` tag while `innerHTML` is used for `<td>` tag.

Also note that you need to sed id for total cell and price cell in oder to read and write in them in your JavaScript function.

```
<td width="20%" class="Text-center" id="percio">
    <?php echo $producto['PRECIO'] ?>
</td>
<td width="20%" class="Text-center" id="total">
    <?php echo number_format($producto['PRECIO']*$producto['CANTIDAD'],2);  ?>
</td>
```